# PHP Generate form action url from multiple selected values. (No Javascript)

Tags: php, forms, url, select

i'm trying to make a search form for a automotive site and i need to generate the form action with the selected values. for example:

```
<form metho="" action="">
<select id="make" name="make" class="select">
<option value="honda">honda</option>
<option value="ford">ford</option>
</select>

<select id="model" name="model" class="select">
<option value="civic">civic</option>
<option value="fit">fit</option>
</select>

<select id="year" name="year" class="select">
<option value="2014">2014</option>
<option value="2013">2013</option>
</select>

<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

So if i choose Honda, civic, 2014 the action would change to: **action="mydomain.com/honda/civic/2014"**

i´ve found this but is in javascript and im dont know how to make it in PHP:

```
$("#gender, #age").on('change', function() {
    var gender = $("#gender").val(),
        age = $("#age").val(),
        site = "somepage.php#"+gender+"-"+age; //inconsistent use of -/_

        $("form").attr("action", site)};
    }); 
});
```

I'm a beginer so sorry in advance.

Comment: You cannot do that in PHP because PHP runs on the server and not on the browser. Make the `method="POST" action="somescript.php"` and in `somescript.php` check the values checked by the user and then redirect to whatever url from there using `header('Location: ' . $theUrl);`

Comment: Thanks i'll try that and let you know how it goes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the comment says above, you cannot change the `action=""` thru the use of PHP. Client-side scripting does that, alternatively, you could submit the form first. Gather the values/input on the same page, then just use a `header()` function after processing the form:

```
<?php
// if its submitted
if(isset($_POST['make'], $_POST['model'], $_POST['year'])) {
    // gather all the values
    $make = urlencode($_POST['make']);
    $model = urlencode($_POST['model']);
    $year = $_POST['year'];
    // make a header redirect
    header("Location: http://www.exampledomain.com/$make/$model/$year");
    exit;
}

?>

<form method="POST" action=""> <!-- leave the action="" empty -->
    <select id="make" name="make" class="select">
        <option value="honda">honda</option>
        <option value="ford">ford</option>
    </select>

    <select id="model" name="model" class="select">
        <option value="civic">civic</option>
        <option value="fit">fit</option>
    </select>

    <select id="year" name="year" class="select">
        <option value="2014">2014</option>
        <option value="2013">2013</option>
    </select>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: thank you very much. Now on to my new challenge, to make this into a wordpress plugin.

Answer (score 0):

You can try somethig like:

```
<?php
if ((isset($_POST['make'])) and (isset($_POST['model'])) and (isset($_POST['year']))) {
    $url = "mydomain.com/".$_POST['make']."/".$_POST['model']."/".$_POST['year']; //with http://
    header("Location: ".$url);
    die();
}
?>

<form method="POST" action="">
<select id="make" name="make" class="select">
<option value="honda">honda</option>
<option value="ford">ford</option>
</select>

<select id="model" name="model" class="select">
<option value="civic">civic</option>
<option value="fit">fit</option>
</select>

<select id="year" name="year" class="select">
<option value="2014">2014</option>
<option value="2013">2013</option>
</select>

<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

But is not the best way to do it.